# Asp.net - Keep Scroll Position after page refresh or reload

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm new to javascript and asp.net.
I'm using linkbuttons in my page and when I click the buttons my page reloads and page scroll to the top.

I tried this script and it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var xPos, yPos;
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(EndRequestHandler);

        function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            xPos = document.body.scrollLeft;
            yPos = document.body.scrollTop;
        }

        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            document.body.scrollLeft = xPos;
            document.body.scrollTop = yPos;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" in page directive

Comment: <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" />

Comment: I used it in web.config file

Comment: do you have any update panel or anyscript on your page which runs asynch?

Comment: i have just checked in web.config file it must be written like <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true"/>, it works

Comment: First question last :D u r using ASP.net web forms or MVC ?